# Getting a substring from a message of string to push in array

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, regex, string

So basically i want to get the user from a message that has a starting special character like "@" or "#" and push it to the user_lists without the special character only the user.

I know about using regex for matching but im having troubled with pushing every match to an array.

```
const user_lists = []
const sample_message = '@user and #user2 has a challenge of time management'
```

My idea was to use includes but it only return as boolean. Please help.

Valid usernames: Without spaces and special character. Just getting all the usernames with a starting @ or #

Comment: read about regex

Comment: what are valid user names? Are `wild poker`, `wild-poker`  or `ƒuß` valid?

Comment: valid usernames without space and special characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `match()`

```
(?<=@|#)\w+
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/XoVgKg/1)

```js
const sample_message = '@user and #user2 has a challenge of time management'

const user_lists = sample_message.match(/(?<=@|#)\w+/g) || []

console.log(user_lists)
```